# Call javascript function after CSS change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function after the css has been changed. For Example something like this

```
$("#ContentDiv").css('height','500px').change(function(){
    alert('changed');   
});
```

Call function immediately after above css change. I cannot use setTimeout or other timeouts. Actually i have applied some css animation for 1 sec which cause contentdiv to resize for 1 sec and that's why if i call a function immediately like this

```
$("#ContentDiv").css('height','500px');
myfunction();
```

myfunction() will start executing while the height is still not changed.

*Thanks to John Smith for correcting my question, he suggested good but i could not find to accept his changes.*

Comment: JavaScript is interpreted in the order you write it. So whatever you write after that line will be executed after that line (unless it is async logic, it's not)

Comment: Plz read the question again @elclanrs. i have edited it for better understanding of what i am trying to ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a DOMAttrModified event that is fired on some browsers that you could catch to detect this. You can probably use PropertyChanged on IE, but DOMAttrModified should work on Chrome/Firefox etc.

Something like this:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', function(evt){
  if (evt.attrName === 'class') {
          // Code 
  }
}, false);
```

EDIT: Based on your update, if you just want to call code after the animation is done, and you are using jQuery to do the animation, you can chain a callback function to the animation, please refer to the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Sorry but can you elaborate more deeply concentrating my above example code.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function.

```
$("#ContentDiv").css('height','500px');
myFunction();
```

Comment: I think the question is poorly worded, but I think he wants to react to the style change regardless of where the code is.

Comment: Sorry that at first i could not explain well.